# Back to the Future : DeLorean Iced after Time Travel

Tags: back-to-the-future

In the first part, there is a scene when Doc shows Marty the demonstration of time travel. Afterwards,when Einstein returned, the DeLorean is covered in ice.  What is the reason for this? If that happened due to time travel, why was it not shown after other time travels?

[image: DeLorean covered in ice]

Comment: I seem to recall it *was* shown on Marty's trips throughout the first film, but after Doc returns from the future at the end with the hover conversion it no longer seems to be an issue.

Comment: Duplicate of [The DeLorean in Back To The Future](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/32128/13418) ?

Comment: @Kalissar Thanks.I got my answer from your link.